# using indexPath from table row in outside function swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

New to swift and for a uni project but i have a table view which holds a record of friends details

The user can have the option to edit a friend or delete a friend.
to do this i created a long tap gesture for delete a friend but i am unsure how to pass the indexPath to the function

this is my current layout:

```
import UIKit

class view_19342665: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var friends: [Friends] = []
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return friends.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friends", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
        cell.textLabel?.text = friends[indexPath.row].displayInfo
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let id = friends[indexPath.row].studentID
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.removeRecord(id: Int(id))
    }
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        friends = appDelegate.getFriendInfo()
        
        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(sender:)))
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
        
        
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 33.0
        
    }
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        return true
    }
    @objc func handleLongPress(sender:UILongPressGestureRecognizer ){
        if sender.state == .began{
            // delete user
            
        }
        else{
            //edit user
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

right now i can delete the row in the table function.

this is what i am trying to achieve:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let id = friends[indexPath.row].studentID

        handleLongPress(id)
    }

func handleLongPress(id : Int){
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
 if sender.state == .began{
            appDelegate.removeRecord(id: Int(id))
            }
else{
  appDelegate.editRecord(id: Int(id))


}
```

can someone please help me delete a row using the ID on a long tap gesture

Comment: I wouldn't use a long tap gesture; table views support the standard swipe left to delete

Comment: i am still learning the basics for swift
is this a complicated task?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcells

Comment: @Paulw11 in the sample code what does object refer to for object.remove
i am getting error "cannot find object"

Comment: In your case it would be your `friends` array.  You also need to remove the data from any persistent store, such as Core Data or whatever you are using.  Also, I wouldn't recommend using your AppDelegate as your data access class. There should be a model class that handles that.

Comment: yes thankyou! i got it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gesture should be added to the table cells inside `cellForRowAt` not to the table itself

```
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(_:)))
cell.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ tap:UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
   guard  tap.state == .ended && let index = tap.view?.tag else { return }
   // use index
}
```